Geometry nodes: How to snap curves points to nearest surface?
I would like to snap all distributed curve points to the nearest surface of the source. See my example.
In my example I'm distributing generated mesh lines on a source mesh (Torus). My goal is to align all the mesh line points onto the source surface. So the lines are "snapping to the surface" / lying on the surface.
Any ideas? Thank you!



To be honest I don't know how to raycast along the source normals.

If you plug the Is Hit socket of the Raycast node to the Selection socket of the Set Position node, you will see that some points are not projectable along the torus normal. Consequently, their Hit Position is (0,0,0), generating the lines to object origin. I need more time to investigate why projection fails. My intuition is that it is when the line is tangent to the normal... Do you have a look at the Shrinkwrap Hair Curves node ?

Are you looking for "just" this case (a torus and straight lines) or a more/very general approach ?

Thank you. I think I've found a first solution to use it for my further work. See my answer below.

I found a solution as a basis for further work.
The basically principle:
I need a projection source for the raycast node to get the ray directions around the source mesh. To achieve this I take the source mesh, extrude it a bit and flip its faces to point the normals back to the source. To get the point normals infos, I capture them from the extruded mesh and connect the data to the raycast node.
It's not perfect, but works in most situations. Thank you for your time.
See my example.


